# Reducing a set of inequalities

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

I have the following three inequalities that needs to be satisfied at the same time
$$\begin{align}
&a > k_2 - k_1 > 0 &(1) \\
&b > k_2 + k_1 > c &(2) \\
&d > k_1 > 0 &(3)
\end{align}$$
where $a,b,c,d$ are positive real numbers. I want to know the conditions on $a,b,c,d$ such that $k_1,k_2$ exists.

Obviously, we need $b>c$. Also, one might naively think to eliminate $k_1$ from the first two equations by adding $(1)$ and $(2)$ to obtain
$$(a+b)/2 > k_2 > c/2$$
and readily $a+b>c$ so we might deduce that only condition for existence of $k_1,k_2$ is $b>c$. However, it is not true for $a=1,b=5,c=4,d=0.1$. And I get that since this operation is one way, i.e. we assume $(1)-(3)$ and deduce something so it doesn't mean the reverse is true.

Another thing we can do is to calculate $(1) + 2 (3)$ to obtain
$$a+2d > k_1+k_2 > 0$$
So we need $a+2d > c$, which seems to work in the reverse direction as well (I couldn't find a counter example).

Why the first method doesn't work but the second one works? How can we get the necessary and sufficient conditions on $a,b,c,d$ that guarantees the existence of $k_1,k_2$?

Comment: $a>c$ and $b>c$

Comment: @Exodd I guess it is sufficient but not necessary.

Comment: It is necessary

Comment: @Exodd It is definitely not necessary. Take $a=1,b=3,c=1.5,d=1$ then $k_1=0.5$ and $k_2=1.25$ satisfies all conditions.

Comment: @Exodd My above example also shows that this is not necessary. Also, do you have any methodology or proof?

Comment: ok I'll write a proper answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first 2 conditions yield a rectangular region in the space $\mathbb R^2$ with coordinates $(k_1,k_2)$. The rectangule has vertices, when $b>c$,
$$
(c/2,c/2) \quad (b/2, b/2) \quad ((b-a)/2,(a+b)/2) \quad ((c-a)/2,(a+c)/2)
$$
we want that this rectangule has some point with coordinates $(x_1,*)$ for some $0<x_1<d$. Since $b$ and $c$ are positive, the rectangule surely contains points with positive $x_1$ coordinate, so we just need to check that the most-left vertex has the first coordinate less than $d$.

Since $c<b$, the vertex $((c-a)/2,(a+c)/2)$ is on the left, so the real condition is
$$2d > c-a$$

This proves that a solution exists if and only if $b>c$ and $a+2d>c$.